# SQL Server trigger to insert added column name from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables, and I want to create a trigger, which will add new added column name as value to another table. So when I will run such query:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA
    ADD ColumnName INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Trigger will do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
VALUES('ColumnName')
```

Is it even possible? I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Look at DDL triggers

Comment: Your schema should be both source-controlled and be rarely altered on an ad-hoc basic. Perhaps you have a very different issue you need to solve with proper development management procedures.

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem, if I am honest. Why not use the system tables if you need to names of the columns in your table?